# CSS unset not working as expected. How to resolve?

Tags: html, css

I `all: unset` to unset all inheritance property but allow user agent stylesheet. How can I do it? As you can see in code it's disabling all styles even user agent stylesheets. How can I prevent user agent stylesheet disabling?

```css
h1, h2 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.editor_data * {
    all: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block">
    <h2>Should be red</h2>
    <div class="editor_data">
    <h1><u><em><strong>Should be underlined, bold, italics, but not red</strong></em></u></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as a side note inheritance doesn't override user agent style so why using unset?

Comment: Perhaps try `initial` instead of `unset`?

Comment: initial property is not working.

Answer (score 8):

Try the keyword `revert` instead of `initial` or `unset`

> The revert keyword is useful for isolating embedded widgets or components from the styles of the page that contains them, particularly when used with the all property.
>
> In user stylesheets, revert rolls back the cascade and **resets the property to the default value established by the user-agent stylesheet**.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert)

```css
h2 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.editor_data * {
  all: revert;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block">
  <h2>Hello world!</h2>
  <div class="editor_data">

    <h1><u><em><strong>Hello world!</strong></em></u></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nobody knows if this will make it to the actual specs. And it is not working in Chrome.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen such attribute value yet that did the trick for me. I reset all margin and padding to 0 with `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` but need it somewhere. unset and initial didn't work. It's a rare case but it's nice that there's a solution. 

2022, working on firefox, chrome and edge btw

Answer (score 0):

You should set `all: initial` on a parent element and then declare `all: unset` for all of it's child elements.

```css
.editor_data {
  all: initial;
}
.editor_data * {
  all: unset;
}
```